# Jquery-generated button not working, closure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, closures

I made this following function :

```
function populatetable(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'backend/conn.php?action=populatetable'
  }).done(function(data){
     var response = data.data;
     $.each(response, function(key, element){
        row += '<tr> <<td>' + element.phone + '</td> <td> <button class="trigger"> Edit Data </button> </td> </tr>';
     }); 
     $('table.loadeddata > tbody').html(row);
  })
}
```

and stored it to a file called `script.js`. Then in another file named `index.php` I included that file within the tag `<script src='script.js'></script>`
and below the above script tag, I made once again a `<script>` and put this following code into the second `<script>` tag :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   populatetable();
   $('button.trigger').click(function(){
     window.alert('button works');
   });
});
```

why did the button not showing the `alert` when clicked?
The button appeared perfectly, it seems that the closure caused the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your assuming your click binding to the button.trigger is happening after the done()?  It may not be.  Why would you not do your binding in the done right after they are created?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous ... the elements don't exist yet when you apply the click handler

Comment: Remove the extra `<` in `<<td>`.

Comment: @charlietfl i think the button also added dynamically by the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

the button is dynamically created, so it is not in the DOM at load time. try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.trigger', function(){
   window.alert('button works');
});
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sn36oyfo/

Read more about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: If you go this route I would suggest the delegate binding be on 'table.loadeddata'

Comment: yes, `body` is not the best - just did it to be safe for example purposes.

Comment: it was brainstorming!! didn't think about that. so in the nutshell, the $(document).ready(function) only works for elements that are loaded at the same time when the page is loaded, not dynamically loaded later when the page has been fully loaded.

Comment: document ready causes the execution of the contained logic to wait until the body is parsed into the dom.

Comment: Yes, see event delegation in my edit. Bind the listener to the closest element already in the DOM